# Aggression or rough play between my two dogs?

Tags: dogs, behavior, aggression, play

My two dogs won't stop biting each other.
This concerns me because of their sizes, I'm afraid that my big dog gets out of control and ends up hurting my little one.
What can I do to stop them from being aggressive? Or do they play like that?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt they are "fighting". This sounds more like rough play. Rough play is common between dogs, especially puppies.

## Aggression or rough play?

It's important to be able to distinguish between aggression and rough play.

If one or both of you dogs are showing any or all of the following signs, it is true aggression:

- Very rigid body
- Raised tail
- Guttural barking or growling
- Showing teeth
- Snarling
- Circling
- Flat or pricked up ears
- Intense staring

I doubt your dogs are fighting, so the next section of my answer is unnecessary, but this is a safety hazard so I am including it anyway:

## How to stop a dog fight

If this is happening between your dogs, it is essential that you stop *all* fighting and take the next steps to prevent it.

To stop a dog fight mid-fight, take these steps:

[image]
Credit: thesprucepets.com

If your dogs are truly fighting, **do not physically intervene** by putting yourself or your hand between them. I know they love you and you love them, but in the middle of a fight, they will bite anything.

Here are some ways to stop a dog fight safely for yourself, and your dogs:

- Assess the situation/determine the aggressor
- Make noise
- Throw a blanket over the bullboxer
- Put an object (like an umbrella) between the dogs
- Pull the legs of your dogs backward (needs two people, also known as the [Wheel Barrow Method](https://www.thedodo.com/yes-there-is-a-smart-way-to-break-up-a-dog-fight-1488888838.html))
- Spray them with a hose
- Remove the dogs from the area
- Take your dogs to a medical professional to assess any injuries

## How to prevent a dog fight

- Feed your dogs separately to avoid aggression over food
- Prevent aggressive situations (like withholding a toy they tend to fight over)
- Provide separate sleeping areas
- Get your dogs used to socialization with other dogs
- Spay or neuter your dogs
- Watch for stress in your dogs (such as stress over thunder)
- Gradually get your dogs used to each other (let them see each other for 15 minutes before removing one dog)
- Exercise and play with your dogs to burn extra energy

## Is rough play okay?

If your dogs:

- are not showing signs of aggression
- are wagging their tails
- playfully bow
- take turns chasing each other
- and have the opportunity to leave the situation but decide not to (in the case of a power imbalance or hierarchy)

Then it is normal. It will develop into a greater friendship and understanding between your dogs.

**Some dogs play rougher than others**. This is also normal. Make sure that if you are having a puppy play date with a dog, not from your household, the other owner understands that your dog is only playing and that they are free to remove their dog from the situation if feeling uncomfortable.

## Summary

Rough play is okay, aggression and fighting are not. If your dogs are fighting,  you need to take further steps to stop it and to prevent it.

It is important for your dogs to have a healthy and equal relationship.

Please consult a trained veterinarian if unsure about any of this.

## Sources

- [Reasons Why Dogs Fight and How to Safely Stop It - thesprucepets.com](https://www.thesprucepets.com/safely-break-up-a-dog-fight-1117894#:%7E:text=A%20method%20that%27s%20sometimes%20successful,dogs%20to%20help%20separate%20them.)
- [How Do You Stop A Big Dog From Attacking A Little Dog? -rehome.com](https://rehome.adoptapet.com/answers/dog-rehoming/how-do-you-stop-a-big-dog-from-attacking-a-little-dog)
- [How To Help Dogs Get Along - cesarsway.com](https://www.cesarsway.com/how-to-help-dogs-get-along/)
- [How to Keep Dogs in the Same House from Fighting - wikihow.com](https://www.wikihow.com/Keep-Dogs-in-the-Same-House-from-Fighting)
- [Is Your Dog’s Rough Play Appropriate? - thebark.com](https://thebark.com/content/your-dogs-rough-play-appropriate)

Comment: nice answer! the little one is the aggressor then because he shows his teeth and stares at him. You may say "ts just a Pomeranian- how much damage can he cause?" well, theres been blood in between this "rough plays".The bullboxer is more patient, he lets the pomeranian "play"for a bit, but then he gets tired of it and starts biting,

Comment: @Isaac750 That sounds like rough play that is dangerously close to aggression or injury. Blood is always a bad sign. Take the measures listed in my answers to maintain a healthy relationship between your dogs. Consider buying (non-rawhide) chews for your Pomeraion if they are too bighty with your bullboxer.